# Should I apply for a new ESTA if I changed my employment status?

Tags: usa, air-travel, international-travel, esta

I am planning to travel to the United States in two days to visit my girlfriend. I have visited the United States four times before and I still have a valid ESTA. The issue is that when I applied for my current ESTA, I was unemployed, but now I have a job and my own business.

Do I need to renew my ESTA or not? I would be grateful for a quick response as I am short on time.

Sidenote: I am Swedish and have no criminal or "bad" records.

Comment: Pretty sure there's a duplicate question somewhere. But the quick answer is your Esta is still valid unless you have new passport or your biographical details (name, birth date, gender designation) changed, or you become otherwise inadmissible to the U.S. or VWP (e.g. criminal record, visits to countries in the designated list, e.g. Syria, North Korea or Cuba).

Comment: ok, Just wondering since the official ESTA website says:
When do I need to reapply for an ESTA?
A new travel authorization may be required in any of the following circumstances:

The traveler is issued a new passport
The traveler changes his or her name
The traveler changes his or her sex
The traveler's country of citizenship changes; or
""""""The circumstances underlying the traveler's previous responses to any of the ESTA application questions requiring a "yes" or "no" response have changed.""""""

Comment: @Mattias was the question about your employment a yes or no question?

Comment: Yes it was, I just called the CBP and they said that I don't need to renew the ESTA. But im still a little worried

Comment: If the CBP says it's OK then definitely believe them rather than random people on the internet. It's normal to be worried, but in this case you don't have to.

Comment: Note: ESTA or visa are not authorization to entry in US. It is just a pre-check. Border officers will evaluate if you are still eligible to entry. So a new ESTA will not change much. Just check that you have good and solid reasons not to overstay or work on US.

Comment: Your ESTA application was approved when you were *unemployed*, a change in that status to *have a job and my own business* is a positive. The other way round would likely mean you’d have needed to renew